# Git clone doesn't get the new revision information from the Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, redmine, git-clone

I am trying to integrate the Gitlab and Redmine. The following is the history of the proceedings.

1. Git clone from Redmine server

   ```
   cd /opt/git_repository/
   git clone --mirror http://userid:password@aaa.com/test.git
   cd /opt/git_repository/
   chown nginx:nginx -R test.git
   ```
2. Repository setting from Redmine

   - settings of ‘test’project – Repositories – new repository

     - SCM: Git
     - URL: /opt/git_repository/test.git
3. Integrations setting from Gitlab

   - Settings – Integrations

     - URL: https://aaa.com/github_hook?project_id=test
     - Secret Token: API access key of Redmine
   - Confirmed success message when I tested

I could see the revision information from http://example.com/test/repository

However, the revision information isn’t upgraded even if it is updated in Gitlab. So, I tried another integration method mentioned from  [How can I clone a private GitLab repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202642/how-can-i-clone-a-private-gitlab-repository)

Still the information is not updated.

Could you help me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to see new information of a repository from the Redmine whenever new events are occured from the Gitlab.