# Convert RSA to OPENSSH

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, rsa, openssh

I will preface this that I am extremely inexperienced with certs/keys and I am using a Mac.

My problem is with RSA and OPENSSH certs/keys. I currently have a valid RSA cert/key, but I need to convert them to OpenSSH. From my understanding, I want to do the opposite of this thread: [Openssh Private Key to RSA Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994641/openssh-private-key-to-rsa-private-key)

I have a file that starts with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I need to convert it to this:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have tried `ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f /path/to/key` and `ssh-keygen -f /path/to/key -m pem` but it does not output with the `OPENSSH` header I expected.

1. Is this possible?
2. If it is possible, what can I use to perform this conversion and what would a potential command be?
3. Do I need to do anything to convert the cert if I converted the key?
4. If I do need to convert the cert, what is the command for that?
5. If there is any further explanation on what converting from RSA to OPENSSH is, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Per documentation at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html 
`Setting a format of “PEM” when generating or updating a supported private key type will cause the key to be stored in the legacy PEM private key format`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As long as you are using `-m PEM` in your command, the result won't be an OPENSSH format.

This will convert an RSA/PEM private key into an OPENSSH one:

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -f /path/to/key
```

You can then extract its public key and confirm it is identical to the one you have before:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f /path/to/key
```

Comment: I think there is some version dependence here. I had to add the ``-o`` argument to get ssh-keygen to output OpenSSH format. This seems to be dependant on versions OpenSSH 6.5 and greater.

Comment: @hydrian True. I am not familiar with 6.x version, and work most often with 7.8 and more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309