# How to clone a Gitlab repository into a GitHub project's workflow

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, github-actions

I want to clone a project hosted on an enterprise Gitlab from GitHub workflow.

```
steps:   

- run: |
    
    git clone https://gitlab.xyz.net/Group/project.git
```

Running above gives me error

```
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.xyz.net': No such device or address
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Comment: Is the gitlab repo public or private? (if private, I suggest looking for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202642/how-can-i-clone-a-private-gitlab-repository))

Comment: Its a private repo

Answer (score 3):

A private GitLab server does not have public repositories by all chances, so you probably need to authenticate for example like this:

```
- name: Clone private repo
  run: git clone "https://username:$EXTERNAL_TOKEN@github.company.com/my-org/my-repo" main
  env:
    EXTERNAL_TOKEN : ${{ secrets.EXTERNAL_TOKEN }}
```